# You will be fine

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, future-tense, past-participles, future-continuous

I have a doubt on this sentence `You will be fine`. I want to know what kind of sentence is this?

As per my research, it is

1. not a sentence in the future continuous form, although it uses, will be
2. It is not in a passive voice because fine is not the third form of the verb. The past participle form of `fine` is fined.

So, What rules does it use to make sentences "You will be fine"?

The thing that I only know about this sentence that it indicates some `future action.`

Answer (score 2):

It is the future tense (or perhaps more accurately a sentence that describes a future time with the modal verb "will").

> You are fine.

Is a simple present tense sentence (not continuous or passive), with a verb "are" (a form of "to be") and a adjective complement "fine" (This is "fine" the adjective meaning "good", not the noun meaning "fee or charge").  To talk about the future, the modal verb "will+bare infinitive" can be used

> You will be fine.

Comment: +1 for unpacking the nonsense about "future tense".

Comment: Could you please explain your answer `+1 for unpacking the nonsense about "future tense". `?

Comment: English doesn't have a "future tense".  There are several ways of modifying the verb phrase to refer to future time, most commonly: Using a modal "will do" or using "is going to do".

Comment: *English doesn't have a "future tense." That's entirely subjective; it depends on who you ask and what terminology and context you are using. While correct from one technical perspective, it's not accurate in terms of how people normally explain language—especially in English learning forums like this.

Comment: Yeah welll, that is why my very first line of my answer says "It is the future tense".  So I think I'm pretty clear in writing for a learner and using the common description of "will do" as a future tense, while also being correct from a technical perspective. It's not subjective, but the claim also isn't in the anwer.